# Why does CreateFile not open files ending in a dot in 64-bit program?

Tags: winapi, filenames, createfile

There is a strange difference in the behaviour of Windows `CreateFile` depending whether you compile your program as 32 or 64 bit.  The former will happily open files ending in a dot (period) while the latter fails with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

For example the following program will depend differently depending on the bitness:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HANDLE h = CreateFile(
        _T("\\bob."),
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);
    return h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it a Windows bug?  Windows 7, if it makes a difference.

Comment: If you're wondering why I would want to open a file name like this, its because `tmpnam` returns them.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a permissions issue? If your current drive is C:\ this will try to create C:\bob and the default permissions prevent files being created in the root of C:\

Comment: @JonathanPotter I think you're right. The 32-bit version creates file in `AppData\Local\VirtualStore` suggesting that I tried to create the file somewhere that UAC doesn't allow.  I guess the question is why doesn't the 64-bit version so this too?

Comment: Also, the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs3e7355.aspx) for `tmpnam` says that, if it returns a path with a backslash prefix, this is "valid for the current working directory".  Perhaps I have to check for that backslash and, if present, prepend the working directory path.